# VS dev server memory usage increase on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, memory-management, asp.net-development-serv

I am using a simple mvc application with an image and a button. But on every postback, memory used by dev server increases and reaches about 100MB in about 50 postbacks.

Is this a known issue about dev server and web applications? Also, mvc is supposed to be stateless but why development server is taking so much space on postbacks. I'm asking this because If I host some complex mvc application in my server and many number of users are accessing my web site at the same time this could crash my server. IIS server are also working like this, any thought about this.

Comment: And in what way is 100MB a problem for the server? You most likely do not have a problem. If you do you will need a realistic test and a profiler.

Comment: I thought each client accessing my server and make it use 100mb might be a problem, if there are about 500 clients. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't have to worry about memory usage of the server. But at the same time you must follow the best practices to write your code. The server decides by itself the best time to collect the garbage and free unused memory.